# iPhone SDK: Making UITextField text in a custom UITableViewCell persist through scrolls?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scroll

I'm aware that to preserve memory usage, `UITableViewCells` are reused when scrolling.  I have some custom `UITableViewCells` that have `UITextFields` in them.  After text is inputted to the `UITextField`, and I scroll, that text is lost because of the cell reuse.

How can I make this text persist through scrolls? I'm thinking I can store each cell's text in its own index of an `NSMutableArray`.  Then, when the cell is reused, I can repopulate it with the array data.

How would I go about doing this? Would someone be so kind as to post a code sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**sample.h**

```
@interface sample : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate>
{

}

@end
```

**sample.m**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    arrData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) // 10- number of fields
    [arrData addObject:@""];
}


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
   return 1;
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

return [arrData count];

}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

     cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
     cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
     UITextField *txt = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:frm];
     txt.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
     txt.tag = indexPath.row;
     txt.delegate = self;
     txt.text = [arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     [cell addSubview:txt];
     [txt release];

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
   [arrData replaceObjectAtIndex:[textField tag] withObject:textField.text];
}
```

Comment: You should check 
if (cell==nil)
before allocation
and textfield's text should be set outside the condition. 
To get the proper textfield's reference either you can use [cell subviews] and find the textfield with its unique 'tag' (set tag of textfield when you allocate it) or you can subclass UITableViewCell and add UITextField in its data members.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I will implement this, and let you know how it goes.